# How to secure SAS drives that were removed from multiple servers?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a few SAS hard drives that were removed from different servers because the servers reported them as faulty (amber light). Some are from a RAID5 arrays and others are from a RAID1 setup.

I have a SAS controller on my PC and apparently it detects some of the drives but not all.
I tried to use DBAN to wipe the ones the controller detected but DBAN was not able to - no error message there.

Are there any other free tools I can use to secure wipe those SAS drives?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

They're beyond use, so you should physically destroy the drives before disposal. Attempting to overwrite them is going to be fruitless because you know they're not reliably reading and writing.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the advise. All I have to do now is hammer them.